# isKindOfClass on id object causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access

Why I tried to use `isKindOfClass` on an `id` object. Sometimes, it went wrong badly and shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Here is the code (will be called when user clicked on Growl notification):

```
- (void)growlNotificationWasClicked:(id)fromUserClick {
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)fromUserClick;
    id object = [[data objectForKey:@"someKey"] unsignedLongValue];

    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"test");
    }
}
```

And here is what inspector showed during the crash:

[image]

Please help me on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: `object` has been probably deallocated or it is not a valid reference at all. Do you have zombies enabled?

Comment: Is there any way to detect or avoid it?

Comment: Where does the object come from and how do you store it?

Comment: @Willeke : I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isKindOfClass` is a method of `NSObject`. When you use `unsignedLongValue`, it returns an `unsigned long` and `unsigned long` isn't an object.

That's why you got crash.

P/S: When you write `[[data objectForKey:@"someKey"] unsignedLongValue]`, it always return a number. You don't need to check the returned value is a number or not. Just use it.

`unsigned long number = [[data objectForKey:@"someKey"] unsignedLongValue];`

Comment: The code in the question does `unsignedLongValue`. And what is the correct code?

Comment: Much better, but maybe add the other solution: `id object = [data objectForKey:@"someKey"];` `if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])`.